# i have some problems with redis6 by docker compose.the acl configuration could not readed by redis

Tags: docker, redis

when i run `config get aclfile`, get response is one empty string,`config get requirepass` is alse empty string

i do not konw why , my file have eny error ?

theres is my dockere-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0
    container_name: redis6
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/redis.conf:rw
      - ./data:/data:rw
      - ./users.acl:/users.acl:rw
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

there is redis.conf

```
# 修改连接为所有ip
bind 0.0.0.0
# 允许外网访问
protected-mode no
port 6379
timeout 0
# RDB存储配置
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
rdbcompression yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
# 数据存放位置
dir /data
# 开启aof配置
appendonly yes
appendfsync everysec
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
# 设置密码
requirepass 123456

aclfile /users.acl
```

there is my users.acl

```
user default ~* +@all >Aa123789~
user test ~* +@all >test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Where mounts `redis.conf` is wrong](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis). Correctly, `/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf`. Or you can change `command` in `dockere-compose.yml`.

```
command: redis-server /redis.conf
```

Comment: any way to make this dynamic with environments and commands rather than mounting config files as volumes???